# If survey is available on website html page then alert me on my email ID using TCL and HTML

Tags: html, email, tcl

Sorry if the  title is inappropriate ..   I'm looking for TCL code which will auto login into website **"http://www.opinionworld.in"** using my gmail  id and password for which I've registered on this website.
After that code should click on my-account tab and after that it should select **"TAKE A SURVEY"** after clicking on this icon website redirects you to a another webpage which is  **"http://dkr1.ssisurveys.com/projects/plist?psid=94mUddoHeetivfuUO0ZREg**&subpanelid=2&css=http%3A%2F%2Fd1g6vijl2fr6nr.cloudfront.net%2Fweb%2FsourceStyles%2Finvo%2Fstyle.css" **and page displays **"Update Your Profile"*** this is the case when there is no Survey to take so website tells you to update your profile instead.
Take A look at another side for which I'm concerned If any survey is available then while you click **"TAKE A SURVEY"** it shows you available surveys whos initials starts with regexp as "ORD-79558-KJTP" or **"ORD-79350-YTBQ".*My concern here is code should automatically login into this website with my gmail id password and select **"TAKE A SURVEY"** and if it reads available surveys as **"ORD-79558-KJTP" or "ORD-79350-YTBQ"** then code should email me on my gmail ID with available survey code like "ORD-79558-KJTP" in subject line and mail should be FROM:me towards TO:me. this process of logging into website and futher lookup should happen after interval of 15 mins... Many thanks for answering this and please update if any further innputs are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-login… that requires code to do cookie handling that I'm working on but which isn't finished yet. (So far, I've got a [partial spec](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/406.html) and an [SCM branch](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/timeline?r=dkf-http-cookies) with some things in it that are about 80% cooked.) Theoretically, you can do cookie handling with the current http package, but you'll need to do quite a lot of work as the cookie specification is not at all trivial (there are parts which are only clear if you try them in practice).

But that's just *part* of what you require to do your task (which seems very complex to me!). The other parts, the taking of http+cookie handling and using it to log into the site, are a major task in themselves. Perhaps you should instead take a few steps backward and see if there is another way to achieve this task? Is there a REST API for accessing the site's service instead? Or has someone else produced an automation library in another language?

Comment: Sir thanks for your valuable feedback .. API part you mentioned seems much more feasible option for me .The part of the code which will deal with accessing the HTML content of the webpage of particular location or initial value seems pretty difficult to me.Sir also share your experience handling such tasks whether my query is feasible for further processing and making it real thing which will work .If it's possible in any other language except TCL.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As Donal said: using an API is the best option, but not always possible.

If you really need cookie based authorization (which I did before with Tcl), it is possible, but not easy. I usually follow this path:

- use a browser plugin like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (Opera and Chrome have such a thing build in) to play through the scenario. Take a look at the network panel, and find the parts that are different for each time you play through this. (You might want to delete the cookies before you login etc.)
- Try to use [`http::geturl`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/24061) to get the same result. You might set some headers, esp. cookies, for some details about cookies with the http package see [the Tcl/Tk wiki on Cookies](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3828), this does not deal perfectly with cookies, but who said you have to?
  If you get a different result, you are doing something wrong. (Some sites disallows cetain user agents, so finding out **why** it did not work might be quite hard)
- Try to extract the different things from the result. You might have to use regexp, some headers, maybe even [tDOM](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1948).

You see, it is a lot of try and error, but possible.

If you finally have your desired result, you can send the mail.
Sending a mail with Tcl is not that hard, there are tutorials out there (in particular, on the [Tcl/Tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1256)).